# Jewish tune to replace "Holy Night" in Harry Chapin's "Mr. Tanner"?

Tags: product-recommendation, chazzan-prayer-leader, music, performance-entertainment

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mr._Tanner):

> "Mr. Tanner" is a song by Harry Chapin from his 1974 album, Short Stories. Big John Wallace plays Mr. Tanner by singing the chorus to "O Holy Night" in the background to the song's chorus.

[Here it is on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=upZB5VlbC6o).

So ... is there any tune or snippet from our tradition that would fit the song well enough that it could be sung instead of "O Holy Night?"

(I know *someone* will vote to close this as off-topic ... but I thought it was worth a try.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on some musical Q&A site. Maybe https://music.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DannySchoemann  I can't win! I tried there and they didn't like it either. https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58695/alternative-to-o-holy-night-that-fits-harry-chapins-mr-tanner

Comment: I think this is on topic. Just as much as a question asking for a bacon substitute for a recipe, for example. It is a question about how to do something in a way that is more Halachicly appropriate. I'm not sure you are likely to get much of an answer, but that isn't a problem with being on topic.